# I have a question

Tags: tense

Is it correct to use "always"in this sentence:"I would always loved to see different countries"?

I have learned that "always"is a frequency adverb that is used at simple present tense.

Comment: might be better to edit the title to be something related to the question itself...

Comment: What exactly do you want to express?

Comment: perhaps I should have asked that before spending half an hour tightening myself into a corner with my ever-broadening 'answer' ;)

Comment: It's "Unclear what you're asking". Your example sentence is ***not valid English***, and there's no point in us trying to second-guess what you *might* want it to mean. Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

"I would always loved to see different countries"
is wrong how it stands.

"Would always" in that context is definitely past tense; implying a long-time regret of something you never did.

IMO, it would always *[though 'would always' in my context is now in the present, even implying future tense... how confusing]* need the word 'have', giving...

"I would always have loved to see different countries"
or better
"I would always have loved to have seen different countries"

If you truly require a 'wish for the future' then it needs to be completely re-cast as perhaps
"I would love to see..."
or
"I have always wanted to see..."

*This one perhaps needs a proper grammarian, rather than my seat-of-the-pants, guesswork based on being native English, analysis. I'm not sure I made anything clearer, or just muddied the waters still further*